# Java: Simple implementation of Command pattern with onComplete callback?

Tags: java, design-patterns, callback, command

Could someone point out where to find an implementation of the Command pattern with onComplete callbacks that could be used for example in a serial macro command?

Comment: The GoF command pattern doesn't include callbacks. Please add some more information or show a url reference to the pattern you really have in mind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
abstract class Command {
    final public void execute(){
          run();
          onComplete();
    }
    protected abstract void run();
    protected abstract void onComplete();
}
//usage
abstract class HiCommand extends Command {
    protected void run(){
        System.out.println("Hi, ");
    }

    protected abstract void onComplete();
}

new HiCommand(){
    @Override
    protected void onComplete() {
        System.out.println("world");
    }
}.execute();
```

or this

```
interface WhenDone{
    void onComplete();
}

abstract class Command {
    private final WhenDone callback;
    protected Command(WhenDone callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    final public void execute(){
          run();
          callback.onComplete();
    }
    protected abstract void run();
}
//usage
class PrintHi extends Command {
    protected PrintHi(WhenDone callback){
        super(callback);
    }

    protected void run(){
        System.out.println("Hi, ");
    }
}

class PrintWorld implements WhenDone {
    public void onComplete(){
        System.out.println("world!");
    }
}
//somewhere
new PrintHi(new PrintWorld()).execute();
```

Examples of  usage isn't from real life. Probably, you should separate creation and calling execution via creation `CommandManager` .

Comment: Thank you, Stas! Hmm... Now I have to figure out how that parent callback command would look like..! I wouldn't deny your input on that. :-)